# Check visibility of item at the screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have FlastList with data. I need to check if item from the Flastlist is seen. So if i do not see data at my screen i do not have to do anything, but if i see i have to console.log data info. And when i am scrolling i have to console.log data that is visibile. I am trying to use onViewableItemsChanged with viewabilityConfig, but when i console.log data, it returns all data from FlastList but not data that is seen. Help me please.

I will be very thankfull!

```js
_onViewableItemsChanged = ({ viewableItems, changed }) => {
  
    console.log("Visible items are", viewableItems.map(item => item.item.text));
};
  
_viewabilityConfig = {
    viewAreaCoveragePercentThreshold: 100
};

//....

<FlatList
   data={this.state.postData}
   initialNumToRender={0}
   ItemSeparatorComponent = {this.FlatListItemSeparator}
   renderItem={({item}) => {
       return (
           <View style={{paddingTop: 15}}
            ref={ (divElement) => { this.divElement = divElement } }
           >
           // data
   
       )}
     }
   onViewableItemsChanged={this._onViewableItemsChanged}
   viewabilityConfig={this._viewabilityConfig}
   keyExtractor={item => item.id}
/>
```

Comment: Can show what is the parent component of the FlatList, and what styles does it have?

Comment: @ischenkodv view and scrollview

Comment: onViewableItemsChanged returns all changes in the current scroll event, if you always want to know whats visible just put it in an array

Comment: @Eric Hasselbring it returns data in array already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your comment you specified that the `FlatList` is inside a view and scrollview. I tried to reproduce it this way:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <ScrollView style={styles.scrollView}>
  <FlatList
    data={DATA}
    initialNumToRender={0}
    renderItem={renderItem}
    onViewableItemsChanged={onViewableItemsChanged}
    viewabilityConfig={viewabilityConfig}
    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
  />
  </ScrollView>
</View>
```

And indeed, `console.log` shows all data in this case. When I removed `ScrollView` so that the `FlatList` is inside the `View` element (with `flex:1`) then it works correctly - `console.log` shows only visible elements. My code:

```
const DATA = [
  {
    id: '1',
    title: 'First Item',
  },
  // ... more elements
];

const Item = ({ title }) => (
  <View style={styles.item}>
    <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
  </View>
);

const renderItem = ({item}) => {
    return (
        <View style={{paddingTop: 15}}
          ref={ (divElement) => { this.divElement = divElement } }
        >
          <Item title={item.title} />
        </View>
    )
}

const viewabilityConfig = {
    viewAreaCoveragePercentThreshold: 100
};

const onViewableItemsChanged = ({ viewableItems, changed }) => {
    console.log("Visible items are", viewableItems.map(item => item.item.title));
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={DATA}
        initialNumToRender={0}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        onViewableItemsChanged={onViewableItemsChanged}
        viewabilityConfig={viewabilityConfig}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      />
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  item: {
    backgroundColor: '#f9c2ff',
    padding: 20,
    marginVertical: 8,
    marginHorizontal: 16,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 32,
  },
});
```